# Open source ALM software stack

Tags: continuous-integration, build-automation, hudson, artifactory, alm

I was looking at open source ALM tools and discovered an interesting project called [jabox](http://www.jabox.org/).

Jabox is a new project designed to support Maven builds and new projects are setup with pre-configured POMs supporting the following suite of tools:

[alt text http://www.jabox.org/images/stories/diagram-bw.png](http://www.jabox.org/images/stories/diagram-bw.png)

What makes Jabox unique is that it contains embedded editions of the following tools:

- Subversion
- Hudson
- Artifactory

Unfortunately jabox does not appear to publish its code, so don't know it's an open source project.

### Question part 1:

Are there any similar open source ALM projects that attempt an integration of existing tools approach?

What interests me is the best of breed approach to ALM.

### Question part 2:

Is there interest in this sort of project? Embedded 3rd party tools in the ALM space and supporting multiple build tools

Maven is not everyone's cup of tea. Some of use still using ANT or looking at other emerging tools like Gradle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse community embarked on a similar ambitious project [Application Life-cycle Framework](http://www.eclipse.org/archived/index.php). Thanks to the indifference by some major ALM tool vendors the project got archived last year.
... and you closed your question yesterday :-)

What Eclipse ALF tried to accomplish seemed to be a major deterrent for commercial ALM vendors. This would have given us a similar tool suite with greater functionality if completed.

Comment: Thanks for that response. I wasn't aware of the Eclipse ALF project.